# Binding a protobuf with nested messages to Golang structs

Tags: json, go, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf message with nested messages including repeated fields (mapping to slices). Going ahead I might have maps too in my protobuf.

I want to bind these ultimately to Golang structs. What is an efficient way to do this?

1. Convert to JSON and then bind that to the structs?
2. Write code to walk through the members and bind them to the struct by calling accessors on the protobuf wrapper in Golang.

I know I should ultimately measure and decide, but wanted to reason about it. It seems to me that #2 would be more efficient as #1 possibly has to do #2 to generate the JSON in the first place. Is that correct?

Comment: Use the proto package to [Unmarshal](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Unmarshal) messages.

Comment: Do you have proto file? If you have, you can easily generate go structs from it using `protoc --go_out=. *.proto` See [link](https://github.com/golang/protobuf)